# Can I update go mod dependence package without adding a new tag for the dependence package

Tags: go, go-modules, glide-golang, golang-migrate

I have two code repository A and B in Go, A depends on B using gomod management. For example, the latest tag version of B is v1.0.1 and the same version in A's go.mod, and then some new commits are merged into B, but without upgrade tag. Can I get the latest changes just by `go get -u A_GIT_PATH`? I try some times, but I can't get the newest B into my local workplace, may gomod's cache causes this problem？

Looking forward for any suggest, thanks so much~

Comment: If you are using Go modules then you can only update to a version that is tagged in version control.  Ie, you will need to tag the B repo with a new tag like 1.0.2 or checkout the code code to another location and use `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up your go.mod to source from local project.

`replace "github.com/userName/otherModule" v0.0.0 => "local/path/the/module"`

eg: [here](https://thewebivore.com/using-replace-in-go-mod-to-point-to-your-local-module/)